# How to get the collection of objects of the `has_many` polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to create a gem ([github](https://github.com/c80609a/c80_sass_seo)) that includes ActiveRecord model `Site` that can be associated with 
`AdminUser` model in the existing Rails application.

model `Site`:

```
module C80SassSeo
  class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
  end
end
```

model `Owner`:

```
module C80SassSeo

  module Owner

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    #  ERROR THROWN: Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern
    # included do
    #
    # end

    def self.included(klass)
      klass.extend ClassMethods
      # klass.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def act_as_owner
        class_eval do
          has_many :sites, :as => :owner, :class_name => 'C80SassSeo::Site'
        end
      end
    end

  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, C80SassSeo::Owner
```

migration for `Site` (`c80_sass_seo_` - table prefix):

```
class CreateC80SassSeoSites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :c80_sass_seo_sites, :options => 'COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci' do |t|
      t.string :url
      t.string :owner_type # NOTE:: without this activeadmin throws an error on index Sites page
      t.references :owner, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    # add_foreign_key :c80_sass_seo_sites, :owners # NOTE:: migration error occurs, comment it
  end
end
```

activeadmin for `Site`:

```
 ActiveAdmin.register C80SassSeo::Site, as: 'Site' do

   scope_to :current_admin_user, association_method: :sites_list

   menu :label => "Sites"

   permit_params :url, :owner_id

   config.sort_order = 'id_asc'

   index do
     column :url
     actions
   end

   form(:html => {:multipart => true}) do |f|

     f.inputs 'Properties' do
       f.input :owner_id, :input_html => { :value => current_admin_user.id }, as: :hidden
       f.input :url
     end

     f.actions
   end

 end
```

BUT I'm getting an empty collection any time I try to access `admin_user.sites` for a AdminUser instance:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Is the correct way to fetch admin users' sites by implementing method like 'sites_list'?

model `AdminUser` (host application):

```
require 'c80_sass_seo/owner'

class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  act_as_owner

  def sites_list
    C80SassSeo::Site.where(:owner_id => self.id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your implementation for the form, you may miss another attributes for the `C80SassSeo::Site` record, which is `owner_type`.

Two solutions:

1. Add `owner_type` as a hidden input, just like `owner_id`
2. Don't add any hidden inputs, create the site with `admin_user.sites.create(parameters)`, and ActiveRecord will take care of the proper association for you

And you mentioned:

```
BUT I'm getting an empty collection any time I try to access admin_user.sites for a AdminUser instance:

=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

When you see this, you should double check if the admin_user actually owns any sites?

```
C80SassSeo::Site.where(owner_id: admin_user.id, owner_type: 'AdminUser')
```

Comment: Adding `owner_type` as a hidden input with value 'AdminUser' and following creating correct record with this fixed form solves the problem. Thank you, Larry!